# jQuery UI's Sortable - how do I style my 'li.ui-state-highlight' ?, always comes up white bg color

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

```
        $("#sortable").sortable({
            placeholder: '.ui-state-highlight'
        });
```

Above that I have in my stylesheet, .ui-state-highlight { background-color: #F6F698; height: 1.5em; line-height: 1.2em; border: dashed 1px gray; }, and whenever I drag an li, the placeholder has just a black border, looks exactly like the normal li's, #sortable li { overflow: auto; margin: 0 0 5px 0; padding: 5px; border: solid 1px black; }.  Am I doing something wrong?  Or missing anything??  Thanks!  When I drag an li, I notice a  shows up, and maybe it's a problem that there's no inner html in that li?  It's closed off immediately (" />" at the end), so maybe it needs an   in there?

Comment: Can you show us an online demo of what you've got? Or post more code?

Comment: <style>
     #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 50%; }
     #sortable li { overflow: auto; margin: 0 0 5px 0; padding: 10px; border: solid 1px black; /* font-size: 1.2em; height: 1.5em; */ }
     html>body #sortable li { /* height: 1.5em; line-height: 1.2em; */ }
     .ui-state-highlight { background-color: #F6F698; height: 1.5em; line-height: 1.2em; border: dashed 1px gray; }
     .ui-state-default { color: #000; font-weight: normal; }
     .ui-state-disabled { opacity: 0.7; background-color: White; }
</style>
... (more in next comment)

Comment: <ul id="sortable"> 

<li class="ui-state-default" id="TopicId-4"> 
 hi there
</li> 

<li class="ui-state-default" id="TopicId-1"> 
 hi again!
</li>

</ul>

Comment: any help appreciated! :)

Answer (score 11):

Don't use:

```
placeholder: '.ui-state-highlight'
```

But use:

```
placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight'
```